# How to load part of a page, and get the attribute from the drop down button without using session

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I surf the net, and there are a lot of php and ajax codes, the problem is i am not really familiar with php, ajax and ccs... and i really need to do this asap.

tried using this but nothing really happened

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#refresh").on("click", function () {

                    $("#center").load("center.html");
                });
            });
   </script>
```

This is the only part that i want to load first...

```
 <div id="refresh" align="center">
        <%                ArrayList<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrder = (ArrayList<PurchaseOrder>) session.getAttribute("poList");
        %>

        <select name="selected" > 
            <%
                for (int i = 0; i < PurchaseOrder.size(); i++) {
            %>
            <option value="<%=PurchaseOrder.get(i).getPoNumber()%>"> <%=PurchaseOrder.get(i).getPoNumber()%></option>
            <%
                }
            %> 
        </select>

    </div>
```

Then this part should load by having the attribute "selected" in the dropdwon

```
<form method="POST" action="ConsumptionReportServlet">
    <div id ="center" align="center">
         <%
        int y = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value"));
         %>

        <table id="dataTable" class="table table-hover" style= "width:800px">
            <tr>
                <th class = "edits">Purchase Order</th>
                <th class = "edits">Item Description</th>
                <th class = "edits">Quantity</th>
                <th class = "edits">Unit Measurement</th>
                <th class = "edits">Unit Price</th>
                <th class = "edits">Vat</th>
                <th class = "edits">Date Made</th>
                <th class = "edits">Prepared By</th>
                <th class = "edits">Approved By</th>
            </tr>         
            <tr>
                <td><%=PurchaseOrder.get(y).getPoNumber()%></td>
                <td><%= PurchaseOrder.get(y).getItemDescription()%></td>
                <td><%= PurchaseOrder.get(y).getQty()%></td>
                <td><%= PurchaseOrder.get(y).getUnitMeasurement()%></td>
                <td><%= PurchaseOrder.get(y).getUnitprice()%></td>
                <td><%= PurchaseOrder.get(y).getVat()%></td>
                <td><%= PurchaseOrder.get(y).getDateMade()%></td>
                <td><%= PurchaseOrder.get(y).getPreparedBy()%></td>
            </tr>
        </table>....
```

The problem is, all the scriplets codes load at the same time??

Error Message, i think this error is due to this

```
  <%
            int y = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value"));
   %>
```

since it get loaded... when there is no "set value" yet..

```
>  HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
> 
> type Exception report
> 
> messageInternal Server Error
> 
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
> from fulfilling this request.
> 
> exception
> 
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
> null root cause
> 
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null note The full stack traces of
> the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish
> Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
> 
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1
```

console error/ glassfish

```
> > Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: null   at
> java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)  at
> java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
> org.apache.jsp.EncodeDeliveryReceipt_jsp._jspService(EncodeDeliveryReceipt_jsp.java:125)
>   at
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>   at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>   at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: do u get any error in console ?

Comment: `center.html` contains ?

Comment: center.html, i though that is the <div id ="center"> ?

Comment: wat was the result comes from `center.html` ?

Comment: the result comes from   ArrayList<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrder = (ArrayList<PurchaseOrder>) session.getAttribute("poList"); then it should populate or get the index of what was clicked in the dropdown

Comment: ok fine `center.html` just remove all your code and start debugging like put the static content like `test or something` check now the result you can get it :)

Comment: i just want to stop the java scriplets in the "center div" to not load...btw I really appreciate your help, thank you :D.

Comment: stop  java scriplets ??

Comment: I want to stop this part of the code from loading <%
            int y = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value"));
   %> since it will always return a null, if there are no attributes pass, i tried changing it to int y=0, and there are no error...

Comment: Im not aware of java sorry